# Can I read and append a slice concurrently if I make sure only one goroutine appending at a time?

Tags: go

I need to concurrently read and append a slice.

```
var s []int
```

I use a channel to make sure there is no cuncurrent append:

```
var ch chan int = make(chan int, 32)
go func(){
    for{
        a := <-ch
        s = append(s, a)
    }
}()
//if I append I call this
func append(int a){
    ch <- a
}
```

As for read, I simply read concurrently:

```
go func(){
    a := s[30]
}()
go func(){
    b := s[35]
}()
go func(){
    var c int
    for x := range(s){
        c+=x
    }
}()
```

is this safe?

If I have more write operations, like changing the element, sorting the slice, is it safe as I make sure only one goroutine writing?

Comment: No, not safe. All accesses must be synchronized, not just the writes.

Comment: "Can I read and append a slice concurrently...?" No. Full stop.

Comment: No, you can't. I'm pretty sure the race detector would've told you this if you used the `-race` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's NOT.

No value is thread-safe in Go, slices is actually a struct, [SliceHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader), it is not safe for concurrent.

[Sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync) package should be used to handle things like this, [RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) may fit your case.

What's more, Go has provided `-race` for checking the concurrent cases, you could try with:

```sh
go run -race main.go
```

Example output:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c00000e060 by goroutine 8:
  main.main.func2()
      /tmp/main.go:22 +0x3c

Previous write at 0x00c00000e060 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/main.go:14 +0xcd

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:21 +0x128

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:11 +0xc4
==================
2
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c00000e060 by goroutine 9:
  main.main.func3()
      /tmp/main.go:26 +0x3c

Previous write at 0x00c00000e060 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/main.go:14 +0xcd

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:25 +0x14a

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:11 +0xc4
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000180018 by goroutine 9:
  main.main.func3()
      /tmp/main.go:26 +0x64

Previous write at 0x00c000180018 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/main.go:14 +0xa9

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:25 +0x14a

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/main.go:11 +0xc4
==================
```